# Twisted word-search

Tags: word-search

This is a somehow twisted word-search.

Every word/phrase should conform to two rules. Your job is to find out the two rules/patterns every word/phrase follows and, of course, to find the words/phrases themselves.

The two rules are mandatory for each and every word/phrase to be considered valid. If either one of the rules is broken, the word/phrase is not valid.

[image]

CSV:

```
S,R,A,G,O,G,R,A,I,L,I  
Y,D,I,R,T,C,I,P,T,G,N
F,D,L,E,P,R,E,H,C,S,K
T,R,Y,G,Y,R,C,Y,U,S,I
E,O,P,E,S,T,O,R,B,E,B
A,Y,W,O,M,E,C,K,E,R,U
I,A,L,R,E,H,A,G,N,B,S
V,L,P,D,S,C,D,R,A,O,B
I,A,G,E,S,A,G,A,M,E,S
S,U,E,L,Z,Z,U,B,E,I,M
E,G,N,A,V,I,P,R,G,V,O
M,Y,I,L,I,R,C,A,L,D,E
B,S,G,M,A,T,I,R,K,O,D
O,L,C,C,I,T,G,D,U,S,U
N,U,S,O,P,P,O,S,B,E,C
G,E,S,C,R,Y,L,N,O,I,T
```

TSV:

```
S   R   A   G   O   G   R   A   I   L   I
Y   D   I   R   T   C   I   P   T   G   N
F   D   L   E   P   R   E   H   C   S   K
T   R   Y   G   Y   R   C   Y   U   S   I
E   O   P   E   S   T   O   R   B   E   B
A   Y   W   O   M   E   C   K   E   R   U
I   A   L   R   E   H   A   G   N   B   S
V   L   P   D   S   C   D   R   A   O   B
I   A   G   E   S   A   G   A   M   E   S
S   U   E   L   Z   Z   U   B   E   I   M
E   G   N   A   V   I   P   R   G   V   O
M   Y   I   L   I   R   C   A   L   D   E
B   S   G   M   A   T   I   R   K   O   D
O   L   C   C   I   T   G   D   U   S   U
N   U   S   O   P   P   O   S   B   E   C
G   E   S   C   R   Y   L   N   O   I   T
```

Hints:

> 1. *Grail* (found in the top row) is not one of the words as it does not follow any of the rules. Even though it could be possibly made to follow one of the rules, there is no way it could be made to follow the other rule.
>
>  2. There is a reason the word-search is called *twisted*.

Comment: I like this puzzle idea, but I think it's a tad too broad. Could you give us an idea of the lengths of the words that we are looking for, or perhaps the number of words to be found using the two rules?

Comment: @Brandon_J, I added hints that could maybe clarify it a bit.

Comment: Can several words share a letter? Are all letters used in the words?

Comment: @MariiaMykhailova, yes, words can share a letter. No, not all letters are used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two rules are:

> 1. Each word/phrase twists into a rectangular loop, possibly with some letters inside.
>  
>  2. Each word/phrase is a tag at Puzzling StackExchange :-)

Here is what I've found so far (20 words total, so that should be it)

> riddle, cipher, cryptography, tiling, rubik's cube, poetry, wordplay, board games, enigmatic puzzle, logical deduction, visual, geometry, trivia, language, sudoku, movies, cryptic clues, checkerboard, algebra, symbols
>  
>  [image]

<strike>It is also possible to relax rule 1 slightly:</strike>

> <strike>If we say that the word needs to have some twists in it, but not necessarily form a full rectangle, we get more words: rebus, liars, game, story, chess, ...</strike>

Comment: Rules are correct, and no, rule 1 is not "relaxed", so the words in the last spoiler do not follow it. :)

Comment: How many words are there total? I rot13(jrag guebhtu gur svefg guerr cntrf bs gntf naq tbg oberq) :-)

Comment: You are missing a few - the total is 20.

Answer (score 1):

The last one is

> symbol (seems that the s is missing...)
> [image]

Comment: nothing is missing, though :)

Comment: so can the s be used twice?

Comment: Exactly :) There are other similar examples